# How to load a numpy condensed matrix into a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I used `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` to calcaulate the distances among indexes of a pandas DataFrame, and as a result it returned me a condensed matrix as a `numpy.ndarray`.

I understand how a condensed matrix works (the top/bottom triangle of a matrix) and managed to load it into a DataFrame by iterating through all DataFrame cells and inserting the respective condensed matrix value.

The problem is that I am calculating the distance among 83.803 boolean vectors, and the result is quite big, which makes difficult to go through all the cells of a 83.803 vs 83.803 matrix and insert its values. Keeping it in mind I would like to know if there isn't any "more intelligent" way to do it! I started working with pandas a couple of weeks ago and realized that its philosophy is to avoid iterating through cells and deal with it as a whole, and that's why I imagine that there is a simple way to load condensed matrices directly.

I am trying to use the `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform` function but it always returns the same error

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Here is the code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from scipy.spatial import distance

>>> content = pd.read_table('proteobacteria-gene_content.tab')
>>> content = content.set_index('Species_name')
>>> content = content.T
>>> content
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 83803 entries, Proteo_1 to Proteo_83803
Columns: 468 entries, Methylomonas_methanica to Glaciecola_sp
dtypes: int64(468)

>>> j_distances = distance.pdist(content, metric='jaccard')
>>> matrix = distance.squareform(j_distances)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: can u show an example of the matrix and your currect code?

Comment: `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`

Comment: thank you cyborg, that is exactly what I needed. It worked when I am using a small matrix. The problem is that the array returned by distance.pdist has 3.511.429.503 elements, and when I run the distance.squareform using this array the python crashes and a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error is returned.